# не выводит ответ в консоль (питон)

Tags: python

```
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.w = w
        self.h = h

    def width(self):
        return self.w

    def height(self):
        return self.h

    def area(self):
        return float(self.w * self.h)

    def perimeter(self):
        return float((self.w + self.h) * 2)


def main():
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    rect = Rectangle(a, b)
    rect.width()
    rect.height()
    print(rect.area(), rect.perimeter())
```

Comment: Вызовите функцию, чтобы потом можно было ввести a и b. У вас программа завершает работу, так как не видит никакого вызова функций или еще чего-либо. Я добавил main() после функции, и все заработало

Answer (score 1):

добавьте в конце файла вызов функции main

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```